AzCopy over SSH error
I'm using Ubuntu and I want to copy a file from a local server to Azure Blob Storage with AzCopy. The command should be executed from server1 and should run on server2 like this:
ssh root@server2 azcopy copy "testfile.txt" "https://..."

If I run the command directly on server2 it works like a charm and the ssh connection works with other commands without problems. However over SSH from server1 I get this error:

401 Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header.. When Uploading blob.

